# How to reference this CSS in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

i have the following CSS for a mouse hover event. Im not sure how to refer to the #tabs ul li a:hover from within the Javascript?

```
#tabs ul li a:hover
{
    color: #000;
    font-weight:bold;
    background-color: #0ff;
}
```

and i wish to swap the background color line for this Javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     hex=255;

     function fadetext(){ 
         if(hex>0) {
             hex-=11;
             document.getElementById("#tabs ul li a:hover").style.color="rgb("+hex+","+hex+","+hex+")";
             setTimeout("fadetext()",50); 
         }
         else
             hex=255;
     }
</script>
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
document.getElementById("#tabs ul li a:hover")
```

isn't valid syntax, you only need to specify the id there:

```
document.getElementById("tabs")
```

You can change the style of an element on hover something like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("id");

elem.onmouseover = function(){
   // your code
};
```

Let's suppose you have assigned the id `myid` to your link, you can do the stuff for that like this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("myid");

elem.onmouseover = function(){
   elem.style.backgroundColor = 'color value';
   elem.style.color = 'color value';
};
```

**Update:**

Since in your code you are using `loadit(this)` in onclick event, you don't need to use `document.getElementById` because element is already referenced with `this` keyword, also you may want to use the `onmouseover` event instead of `click` event if you want to something to happen when element is hovered like:

```
<li><a href="tab-frame-workexperience.html" target="mainFrame" onmouseover="loadit(this)" >Work experience</a></li>
```

and then your function should look like this:

```
function loadit(elem)
{
   elem.style.color = 'color value';
}
```

and/or you can create the two functions for two events if you want.

**Note** also that you can use [jQuery](http://jquery.com) to do it easily and in unobstrusive fashion with **[`hover`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/)** method:

```
$(function(){
  $('#tabs ul li a').hover(function(){
     $(this).css('color', '#ff0000'); // this fires when mouse enters element
  }, function(){
     $(this).css('color', '#000'); // this fires when mouse leaves element
     }
  );
});
```

Comment: This is the declaration for the tab links:

<div id="tabs">
<ul>
     <li><a href="tab-frame-css.html" class="selected" target="mainFrame"  onclick="loadit(this)" >Personal details</a></li>
     <li><a href="tab-frame-education.html" target="mainFrame"  onclick="loadit(this)" >Education</a></li>
     <li><a href="tab-frame-workexperience.html" target="mainFrame" onclick="loadit(this)" >Work experience</a></li>
</ul>
</div>


I tried ById("tabs") but that didn't work either

Comment: @John: Post your attempted code in your question please with clear explanation. Thanks

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: nope, i am not using any for answers here :)

Comment: Then where did those dots (I removed) come from? :P

Comment: @Marcel Korpel: Which dots are you talking about?

Comment: The leading dots in the code in the [third version of your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/12db23d9-bacb-4868-9ec8-e9105e2001d2/view-source).

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to edit your stylesheet instead of changing the style of every element, this can be done with a simple one-liner:

```
document.styleSheets[0].insertRule("#tabs ul li a:hover{rgb(255, 255, 255);}", 0);
```

Where the second argument specifies that the rule should be inserted first in the stylesheet.

For IE this is done with the addRule function instead:

```
document.styleSheets[0].addRule("#tabs ul li a:hover", "rgb(255, 255, 255)");
```

**Update:**

In your case, it would mean replacing this row:

```
document.getElementById("#tabs ul li a:hover").style.color="rgb("+hex+","+hex+","+hex+")";
```

with

```
var ss = document.styleSheets[0]; //gets the first external stylesheet in your document
if(ss.insertRule) //checks browser compatibility
  ss.insertRule("#tabs ul li a:hover{rgb("+ hex + ", " + hex + ", " + hex + ");}", 0);
else
  ss.addRule("#tabs ul li a:hover", "rgb("+ hex + ", " + hex + ", " + hex + ")");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this? This didn't work...

```
#tabs ul li a:hover
{
    color: #000;
    font-weight:bold;
    <script type="text/javascript">
            hex=255;
            var elem = document.getElementById("tabs");
            elem.onmousehover = function fadetext(){ 
            if(hex>0) {
                hex-=11;
                elem.style.color="rgb("+hex+","+hex+","+hex+")";
                setTimeout("fadetext()",50); 
            }
            else
                hex=255;
            }
        </script>
}
```